# How to programmatically run ansible playbook using aws_ssm connection plugin in python

Tags: plugins, ansible, aws-ssm

There are multiple examples to run ansible playbook using PlaybookExecutor using SSH connection. But I'm unable to find any example that uses aws_ssm connection plugin to run ansible playbook. Can anyone provide an example of it?

Comment: The documentation on ssm_connection on the ansible site has examples at the bottom of the page https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/aws_ssm_connection.html

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I want example of running playbook programmatically,  like this example https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html. That example uses "smart(ssh)" connection. I want to use "aws_ssm" connection instead.

Comment: Ah I see, there is very little about using SSM connection in general I imagine there will be even less for the API version